# Is it possible to rename a player in Age of Empires 1?

Tags: age-of-empires

I would like to change the name of a player that I use in the campaign mode in Age of Empires I: is there any way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As in your screenshot, you are stuck with the `New` and `Remove` options only.  Your progress is linked to the `game?.nfo` file (replace ? with a number, starting from 0, for each player).  I couldn't see a way of amending this in the file.  You can examine the file yourself by looking in the directory that contains your EMPIRES.exe.

The only practical way would be to create a new player and then use the `home run` cheat to skip all the levels you don't want to replay.

To perform the cheat, press enter to go into chat mode then type in `home run`.  On pressing enter again you will automatically win the level.